# Async, waterfall issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, asynchronous, async-await

Here i am trying to retrieve all the objects and push them into the `json` file.  For some reason there is only one record being pushed into file when it should contain more objects. The response is being sent even before the execution. Can you help me out with this or let me know where I am going wrong? Here is my code:

```js
exports.createjoson = (req, res) => {
  const Responsearray = [];
  async.waterfall(
    [
      function(waterfallCb) {
        //  ... first function
      },
      function(results, waterfallCb1) {
        //second function
        async.eachLimit(
          results,
          100,
          function(singleResult, eachCallback) {
            async.waterfall(
              [
                async function(innerWaterfallCb) {
                  try {
                    NewsModel.find(
                      { _id: singleResult.newsId }, // #individual article
                      async (err, newsResult) => {
                        if (err) {
                          return innerWaterfallCb(
                            // #displaying error
                            "error in fetching news data"
                          );
                        }
                        const map = new Map();
                        for (const item of newsResult) {
                          if (!map.has(item.source)) {
                            map.set(item.source, true);
                            Response = {
                              newsId: item._id,
                              title: item.title,
                              comment: singleResult.comment
                            };
                          }
                        }
                        resPond = await Response;
                        Responsearray.push(resPond);
                        let data = JSON.stringify(Responsearray);
                        await fs.writeFileSync("abc.json", data);
                      }
                    );
                  } catch (error) {
                    innerWaterfallCb(error);
                  }
                }
              ],
              function(err) {
                if (err) {
                  return eachCallback(err);
                }

                eachCallback(null);
              }
            );
          },
          function(err) {
            if (err) {
              return waterfallCb1(err);
            }

            waterfallCb1(null);
          }
        );
      }
    ],
    function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(200).json({ status: "400", message: err });
      }
      res.status(200).json({ status: "200", message: "success" });
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with the code:

1. `fs.writeFileSync` will overwrite the file, not append to it, so only the last data you write will be in `abc.json`. Also it does not return a `Promise` so there is no need to use `await` on it. It runs synchronously so will not return until it's complete (that's what the `Sync` in its function name means). To append instead of overwrite the file, you can set the flag option to "a" to append (the default is "w").
2. There doesn't seem to be a call to return `innerWaterfallCb(null)` anywhere - only in error conditions. The inner waterfall function shouldn't be marked `async` since it doesn't need to do any `await` calls really. But you should call `return innerWaterfallCb(null)` after the file is written.
3. It may be better to just collect the data in `responseArray` and write the file once at the end of the outer waterfall instead of writing it repeatedly deep inside the inner waterfall.
4. Variables should start with lowercase letters (like `responseArray` not `ResponseArray` since uppercase first letters indicate classes or modules usually.
5. Don't mix `async/await` with the async module (waterfall and eachLimit). If you're using proper Promises and `async/await` then there should be no need to use the async module. It would be cleaner to remove the use of `waterfall` entirely and rewrite to use `Promise` objects properly.

Comment: thanks, i rewrote the code using promises . now the issue i am facing is all the objects are being pushed to array but i am not able to write it to a file

Comment: what happens? I assume you stringify then write that string to a file as before

Comment: i have posted another question regarding the same , after i made changes to api . can you have a look at it ?